# Response class with polymorphic property hides deriving classes

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swashbuckle, .net-4.8

I have a response class that looks like this:

```c#
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "List of something returned", Type = typeof(APIResponse))]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage QuerySomething()
{
    ...
}
```

The `APIResponse` class looks like this:

```c#
public class APIResponse
{
    public string Something { get; set; }

    public IResponseDetails ResponseDetails { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the property `ResponseDetails` is an interface, and I put other classes there, depending on the logic. For example:

```c#
public class SomethingDetails : IResponseDetails 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**So, the problem is:**

When I generate the swagger json file, I don't see anything about the `SomethingDetails` class.
Only `IResponseDetails` appears as a class:

```c#
public partial class IResponseDetails 
{
}
```

How can I expose the deriving classes like `SomethingDetails`?

Comment: Isn't that how it is supposed to work? You expose the interface, not the implementation. Why should your API client need to know anything about SomethingDetails class?

Comment: @Shameel, the client would be interested to know what fields they should expect in 'IResponseDetails' rather than getting it as an empty class ang guessing what can be in it...

Comment: then those fields should be declared as part of the iResponseDetails interface and implemented in the SomethingDetails class.

Comment: But SomethingDetails is just one example, other classes implement this interface with different fields. If I knew what class will be returned, I would've used a class instead of the interface...

Answer (score 0):

First thing install from nuget: [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcoreannotations)

Then,you have to enable annotations on Startup:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(config =>
    {
        config.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Title = "title",
            Version = "1"
        });

        config.EnableAnnotations();//try adding this line
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I use .net framework 4.8 so this package won't work for me.